# Play Framework: Make Threadlocal consistent per request in Async actions

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, playframework-2.0, thread-local

In Play Framework, if your code runs within Future, it jumps from one thread to another. I have a config object which is instantiated per request, and need to be stored in the Threadlocal. However when the Future is involved, Threadlocal values aren't consistent anymore. How do we try to make the Threadlocal consistent throughout the life of request even if it is jumping between different threads?

Thanks

Comment: You should really avoid that sort of global state given that Play is stateless.  If you do need something global (like a DB connection pool), I'd recommend creating a plugin and putting it there: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaPlugins

Comment: Its not really a global state, it is state per request. If each requests were handled by a single thread, it makes sense to use threadlocal. The problem here is, with async requests, threadlocal is not consistent throughout lifespan of request.

Comment: If it's per-request, why does it need to be stored anywhere?  Just pass it to whatever function needs that object.  Implicit parameters are good for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpExecutionContext. Please refer https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ThreadPools#java-thread-locals.